# Can you concatenate two strings to create dynamic column names in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a form where people can type in a start and end date, as well as a column name prefix.

In the backend, I want to do something along the lines of

```
SELECT *, CAST('{{startDate}}' AS TIMESTAMP) AS ({{prefix}} + '_startDate')
```

Is this possible? Basically, I want to dynamically create the name of the new column. The table is immediately returned to the user, so I don't want to mutate the underlying table itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can execute dynamic query that you have prepared by using `EXECUTE` keyword, otherwise it is not possible to have dynamic structure of SQL.

Since you are preparing your SQL outside database, you can use something like:

`SELECT *, CAST('{{startDate}}' AS TIMESTAMP) AS {{prefix}}_startDate`

Assuming that `{{prefix}}` is replaced with some string by your template before it is sent to database.